# How to add active class to menu (based on url hash)

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have a anchor link menu:

```
<ul>
  <li class="anchorX"><a href="#anchorX">Bla</a></li>
  <li class="anchorY"><a href="#anchorY">Bli</a></li>
  <li class="anchorZ"><a href="#anchorZ">Blu</a></li>
</ul>
```

now I want to add an active class to the `li` element based on the current hash in the url.

Since there will be no page reload I've tried to write a function which is listening to te url:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    //get the hash
    var adressBarHash = window.location.hash.replace("#",".");

    //now apply the class active to the link which contains the same hash as a class
    $("ul").find(adressBarHash).addClass( "active" );
});
```

My idea is to match the hash in the url with the class. But I can't get it to work.

Even better would be to match the hash in the adress bar with the hash in the href tag but thats out of my league.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    var adressBarHash = window.location.hash;
    $('[href*=' + adressBarHash + ']').addClass('active')

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: oops, didn't see that you wanted it on the li

You almost have it.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  let hash = window.location.hash;
  $('a').closest('li').removeClass('active');
  $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/47288/

Comment: Is it possible to apply this `on hashchange` as well as `on pageload`. If somebody has a bookmark with the hash already applied and loads the site it gets executes as well.

Comment: Oh yeah, I don't see why not.  I can try to test it out.